# why datetime.now not work when I didn't use tolist?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

When I use

```
datacontext.News
    .Where(p => p.status == true)
    .Where(p => p.date <= DateTime.Now)
    .ToList();
```

the system will return no results;

When I use

```
datacontext.News
    .Where(p => p.status == true)
    .ToList()
    .Where(p => p.date <= DateTime.Now)
    .ToList();
```

system will return expected results. Can anyone tell me what's up?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You don't need the `== true` if it is a bool. just have p => p.status in the where call.

Comment: Can you show us the SQL queries that get executed on the background? You can do this by attaching a TextWriter to the datacontext. Example: `datacontext.Log = Console.Out;`.

Comment: If you remove the second `Where` clause, what type does the expression return?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but it's usually recommended to assign  `DateTime.Now` to a variable and then using the variable for comparison when iterating over the data. `DateTime.Now` will change over time and this may affect the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I best guess is that the time settings on your database server differ from that on your developer machine (or the machine you run .NET on).

The difference between the two snippets is that in the second snippet the condition `p.date <= DateTime.Now` is executed locally, and not on the database server.

If you want to use local time, you can do this:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var newNews = datacontext.News
    .Where(p => p.status == true)
    .Where(p => p.date <= now)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use multiple `.Where()` ?

```
datacontext.News
    .Where(p => p.status && p.date <= DateTime.Now)
    .ToList();
```

would also work.

This answer may also help you understand why it doesn't work as expected: [Can multiple compiled linq queries be chained together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544006/can-multiple-compiled-linq-queries-be-chained-together/1544288#1544288)

Comment: -1 : He's not using compiled queries and there's nothing wrong with chaining Queryable.Where

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to ask it this way...

```
datacontext.News
    .Where(p => p.status == true && p.date <= DateTime.Now)
    .ToList();
```

or

```
datacontext.News
    .Where(p => p.status && p.date <= DateTime.Now)
    .ToList();
```

the " == true" is only help to understand a little better what on the question.

Comment: This looks nicer but chaining where clauses should produce the same result.

Comment: @Leom Its seems that chaining need first to be List again to work. Maybe its an issue for chaining on linq to sql

Answer (score 0):

Its the difference between .NET evaluating date comparisons and SQL; ToList() executes the response and so I think the second where is using LINQ to Objects.  For date comparisons, you can also consider SqlMethods

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods_members.aspx

And so you can use:

```
SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(d1, d2) > 0
```

If dates aren't still working for you.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Check out result in the debugger to see differences between the database server's time and the local time.

```
var result = datacontext.News
  .Take(1)
  .Select(n => DateTime.Now)
  .ToList()
  .Select(x => new {SqlTime = x, LocalTime = DateTime.Now})
  .Single();
```